# "Invalid Column Name" error on old database value

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have made changes to my database on one of my table. Before I had this field:

```
ORDER_AMOUNT
```

which was a `NUMERIC(5,2)` field.

The field has been renamed like this:

```
ORDER_DETAIL_AMOUNT
```

But ever since then each time the app tries to take something from this table, this error occurs:

```
Invalid column name 'ORDER_AMOUNT'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ORDER_AMOUNT'.
```

I'm completely new to MySql and I'm using Visual Studio 2012, can anyone help me out understand what's the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: maybe a dumb question but have you changed the code to use the new name?

Comment: @PatrickEvans It's probably what happened. This is what the error suggests and since OP's new to MySQL and .Net ...

Comment: Not a dumb question, only dumb answers ^^ Well I've passed through my code, there's no errors, and the model has the correct ORDER_DETAIL_AMOUNT mapped. But the error still occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing then : You renamed it in the design so you have to rename it in your app to.

There is probably a place where you refer to `["ORDER_AMOUNT"]`. Now the app expects to see this column in the database. Since it is now called `["ORDER_DETAIL_AMOUNT"]` it won't find it and will give you the error.

Change the name in the app. And *Voila*.

Comment: Hum, yeah, you are right on the typo, but... it actually occurred while typing this post, not in the app. I've just checked it twice. Sorry, will fix this. ^^

Comment: Well, you forced me to check once again in my code. I've double-checked every values, and maybe there WAS a typo through the mySql code, but now it's fixed, so thanks ^^

Comment: Will do once the time delay goes out.